# ros buildfarm: package build failed because include not found

Tags: ros, catkin, buildfarm, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I submit my package into the ros buildfarm. It can be compiled successfully on local machine and in travis-ci.org

But in ROS buildfarm it says:

> Command failed, exiting.  Project
> 'dji_sdk_lib' specifies 'include' as
> an include dir, which is not   found.
> It does not exist in
> '/tmp/catkin_workspace/install_isolated/include'.

However, there is a include dir in my package https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/tree/3.1/dji_sdk_lib

So I'm puzzled and wondering how to fix this error? Is it caused by I didn't specify a install parameter in the CMakeLists.txt?

the overall log: http://build.ros.org/job/Idev__dji_onboardsdk_ros__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/1/console and
error message shows in 00:03:48

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230194/ros-buildfarm:-package-build-failed-because-include-not-found/) by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2016-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your package does not specify any installation rules; so when the build farm tries to install your package, it fails.

Have a look at the [catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) and in particular the documentation for [building and installing C++ libraries](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2016-03-26**:
thanks @ahendrix I will fix it. 1. Do all released packages need to specify a install parameters? 2. When one pkg needs another one as a library, the buildfarm also said it failed cause cannot find the library package, is it the same problem? i.e. no install parameter in the library package

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-26**:\

1. Of course. 2. Very likely.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-03-26**:
The best local testing prior to building debs is to use `catkin_make_isolated --install` to validate you have setup install rules. And use the install space instead of the devel space.

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2016-03-27**:
thanks @joq and @tfoote , sorry I'm a newbie in pkg release =.=